# how to use mysql one field AND

Tags: mysql

My simple question about mysql

This is my code

```
SELECT
    t_id_tags.id_post,
    t_id_tags.id_tag
FROM
    t_id_tags
WHERE
    id_tag IN (860, 945)
```

I'm like this

```
SELECT
    t_id_tags.id_post,
    t_id_tags.id_tag
FROM
    t_id_tags
WHERE
    id_tag = 860
AND id_tag = 945
```

is possible ?

tnx

Comment: I would clarify what your trying to accomplish a bit more.

Comment: The bottom should return nothing since something can't be 860 and 945.

Answer (score 0):

If you want posts with both tags, then one method is to use aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT t.id_post
FROM t_id_tags t
WHERE t.id_tag IN (860, 945)
GROUP BY t.id_post
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

If you can have the same tag assigned multiple times on a post, then use `COUNT(DISTINCT t.id_tag) = 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The AND option means both must be true not either. You may want OR to say if one or the other is true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want results for tag_id = 860 as well as 945 then use following Query:

```
SELECT t_id_tags.id_post, t_id_tags.id_tag
FROM t_id_tags WHERE id_tag = 860 OR id_tag = 945
```